# Environments in VSTS releases

Tags: azure-pipelines

I'm trying to wrap my head around how we can configure our release management to use [Environments](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/definitions/release/environments). Let's say our architecture has an Angular front-end and WebApi projects that sit on the web server and a WCF project that sits on our app server (so 3 projects total). In addition, we have Test, Stage, and Production environments.

Am I correct in my understanding that we would create 1 Release definition with 3 environments. Would each environment definition consist of the tasks to deploy the necessary artifacts for all 3 projects to the necessary folders/servers for that environment?

Is this how it should work? The documentation isn't bad, but I need more of a real world, concrete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This scenario is similar to database and web tiers of an application.

> These should be modeled as a single environment because you want the
>   two to be in sync. If you model these as separate environments, you
>   risk deploying one build to the database environment and a different
>   build to the web tier environment.

Not clear about the relationship between WCF project with other projects. If Angular app needs retrieve data from WCF too, you can create a release definition with 3 environments (Test, Stage and Production), then the workflow will be like this:

1. Deploy these projects to corresponding servers for Test environment
2. After testing, approve to deploy to Stage
3. Approve to deploy Production

If there isn’t the relationship between WCF project with other projects, you can create another release definition with 3 environments for this project.

Comment: Yes, the WCF services supply data to the public API (webApi) project. So, should there be a release definition for 1. the Web app with "Environments" for Test, Stage, Production 2. the WebApi project with "Environments" for Test, Stage, Production 3. the WCF project with "Environments" for Test, Stage, Production? Or, am I misreading this?

Comment: One more thing, if the TEST environment is set up with CI (push to TST Branch) the STAGE environment is set with CI (merge to stage) and the PRODUCTION environment is manual deployment, it looks like the manual deployment for PRODUCTION will also re-deploy the other environments. Is this correct?

Comment: @MattM Yes, a release with Test, Stage, Production environments and add tasks to deploy these apps in each environment.

Comment: @MattM For this scenario, you separate Test and Stage, so you can have 2 release definition, one for Test (a Test environment) and another for Stage and Production (Stage and Production environments). Regarding deploy to Production environment, you just need to approve to deploy instead of in a new release. (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/definitions/release/environments#approvals)